# Songs & Artists from Haikus

Tags: riddle, music

The goal is to determine the song title and artist from these haikus. All the artists will have received mainstream success in some form.

**Haiku #1**

```
"A possessor of
marionette expertise."
- Alloy Performer
```

**Haiku #2**

```
"Degradation of
one's overall attitude."
- One Extra Digit
```

**Haiku #3**

```
"A compilation
of objects, short in stature."
- Eyes Closing Often
```

**Haiku #4**

```
"Within an insect's
abode, a transformation."
- Superb Resonance
```

**Haiku #5**

```
"Rock's adversary
opening layers of skin."
- Chi Town Neighbourhood
```

*The haiku itself holds no significance over the answer.*

--

***Some information about myself (to be used as hints, if you wish):***

I'm from

> North America.

Specifically

> Canada.

I was born during

> the mid 80's.

My favourite types of music are

> some form of Rock 'n' Roll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haiku 1

> Master of Puppets, Metallica

Haiku 2

> Drag You Down, Finger 11

Haiku 3

> All the Small Things, Blink 182

Haiku 4

> Change (In The House Of Flies), Deftones

Haiku 5

> Papercut, Linkin Park

Answers for 1,2,3 and 5 were previously provided and confirmed by OP.
Adding answer here for the 4th Haiku.

Comment: Ah, I get it. "Deft" "tones". I've always just read it as one word, so I guess it slipped my mind. :(

Comment: i read it as "Def" - http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=def

Answer (score 1):

Haiku #1 is

> Master of puppets from Metallica

Haiku #3 is

> All the small things from Blink 182

Comment: Correct so far.

Answer (score 0):

1.

> Master of Puppets: Metallica

2.

> Drag You Down: Finger 11

3.

> All the Small Things: Blink-182

4.

> Hmm....

5.

> Papercut: Linkin Park

Comment: You got those four quick! I probably should've formatted them having the artist's name mixed in with the title. Oh well, first puzzle!