# Songs & Artists from Haikus #2

Tags: riddle, music

I've always been fascinated by my older cousin's taste in music. Such variety. But they never make it easy to borrow their music, and I have no money to buy my own. So I must do their bidding.

This time around, I have to decipher 5 riddles to uncover 5 songs titles and their performers. However, my cousin told me the clues to the song title and its performer are mixed together and not necessarily in order.

I don't even know where to start. Can someone help me figure this out?!

**Haiku #1**

```
Lips pursed belvedere.
Afloat in wavy water
as moonlight passes.
```

**Haiku #2**

```
Charlie's steps rapid.
His delta bests Mike's. Alas,
lone on a boulder.
```

**Haiku #3**

```
"Excuse me", muttered
the one whose day job consists
of wheeling stacked crates.
```

**Haiku #4**

```
Move with haste, away
from the unmarried lady,
towards mounds of ore.
```

**Haiku #5**

```
A holy vessel,
untouched, performing what looks
like idol worship.
```

--

Some hints from [this post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43707/songs-artists-from-haikus) can be applied here

**Additional Hints**

> Not all words in a haiku translate to the solution. Take #4 (which already has a solution) for example:
>  
>  **Move with haste**, away (run)
>  
>  from the **unmarried lady**, (maiden)
>  
>  towards **mounds** of **ore**. (hills, iron)

Another hint

> #1 is rock. #3 is country. #5 is pop

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer here:

Haiku #4:

> Run to the Hills by Iron Maiden

Haiku #5:

> Like A Virgin by Madonna

Comment: #1 is incorrect. #4 is partially correct.

Comment: Okay, I've changed my answer for #4, hope this one is right. :)

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer -
Haiku 2:

> King of Rock, RUN DMC
>  -- steps rapid = RUN; delta, Mike, Charlie = DMC
>  -- lone on a boulder = King of Rock)